# Invalid syntax near *args in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, args

I keep getting invalid syntax at `*args`.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
cmd, *args = sys.argv[1:]
globals()[cmd](*args)
```

I'm trying to pass multiple arguments to the functions in code.

Comment: `cmd, *args = sys.argv[1:]` is definitely a syntax error in Python 2

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Note that `globals[cmd](*args)` suggests you're perpetrating something heinous - once you have it working, I'd suggest a trip to [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use [*Extended Iterable Unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), which is available starting from Python 3.

You'd replace it with

```
cmd = sys.argv[1]
args = sys.argv[2:]
globals()[cmd](*args)
```

to make it work in Python 2.

Comment: Or just `globals()[sys.argv[1]](*sys.argv[2:])` if those names aren't reused.

Comment: Thanks but when I run it I get  Keyerror:    for  `globals()[cmd](*args)`

Comment: Probably because `sys.argv[1]` is not in [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals). @Analytics360